# Shape Similarity Metric for Binary Images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, shapes, shape-recognition

I have binary images that has various shapes in it. I would like to measure the shape similarity between two binary images. Is there any good measure for this purpose?

Comment: Do you have sample images? Try making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Hausdorff distance

Comment: how do you define shape similarity between two binary images? provide images. it doesn't make sense to discuss image-processing without images.

Comment: You have asked a whole string of vague questions with neither sufficient explanation, nor code, nor images. This is not a good fit for Stack Overflow which is dedicated to answering specific coding questions. Please improve your questions or they are likely to get closed.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends similarity from which point of view? The best way to show it is to post "Similar" and "Unsimilar" sample images.
Your direkt answer is:
"XOR the two images, and sum up all the pixels, the bigger result is the most unsimillar."
But I think you have a more challenging problem.